# How to get the text value of a datepicker?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I am trying to get the text value of a datepicker so that I can store it in a MySQL database.

Here is a sample of my HTML code (index.php):

```
   <div class="col-xl-6">
       <input id="datepicker2" placeholder="Date">
   </div>

    <div class="col-xl-12">
        <a href="#form3" class="popup-with-form">
            <button type="submit" class="boxed-btn3" onclick="customFunction()">Next</button>
        </a>
    </div>
```

Here is the JavaScript code (within index.php):

```
    <script>

      function customFunction() {
       
          var DateOfBirth = document.getElementById("datepicker2").value;
           
          if (DateOfBirth != null && DateOfBirth !="") {
                $.post("insert.php", {DateOfBirth : DateOfBirth },function(response){
                    console.log(response);
                });
            }   
 
       }

   </script>
```

Here is the insert.php file code:

```
 <?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "testdb";
    
    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }
    
        $Date = isset($_POST['DateOfBirth'])?$_POST['DateOfBirth']:'';

    
    $sql = "INSERT INTO datepick (SinceDate) VALUES ('"$Date"')"; 
        
    
    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "New record created successfully";
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }
    
    $conn->close();
    ?>
```

The issue I am having is that I am unable to get the text value of the datepicker. Does anyone know a solution to this?

Comment: Could you share the insert.php code.

Comment: Do you use a datepicker library? And if so, do you use the library methods?

Comment: @JorgeMejia code added.

Comment: @ManuelGuzman  Its a Bootstrap 4 datepicker. I don't know exactly which library it uses.

Comment: Try to name the input field and log the full form

Comment: Can you write an example please, I didn't understand what you meant here.

Comment: Someone please help. I'm struck on this for days.

Comment: In your index.php this input <input id="datepicker2" placeholder="Date"> displays the date ?

Comment: Your http request to index.php returns something ?

Comment: @JorgeMejia Yes the input displays the datepicker.

Comment: @JorgeMejia nothing is returned. It just displays the index.php page.

Comment: Is your button inside a form tag ? if not try remove the type="submit" from it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem of the empty post in your insert.php script is the fact that your JS doesn't properly send the data to the php script. I played a bit with your example on my own dev environment and i managed to make it work.

The only thing i changed in your index.php is that i gave your button an id so i can call it from javascript and i moved the javascript code in a separate file. I've been running a content-security-policy for so long that i just can't leave inline js anymore.

index.php

```
<div class="col-xl-6">
       <input id="datepicker2" placeholder="Date">
   </div>

    <div class="col-xl-12">
        <a href="#form3" class="popup-with-form">
            <button id="submit-button" type="submit" class="boxed-btn3">Next</button>
        </a>
    </div>

    <script src="js.js"></script>
```

I will use native JS and with new ES6 synthax and will also remove your JS from inline event hanlers (better anyway). Also i will not be using the jQuery ajax but native javascript fetch. So i've put your js in a file called js.js

js.js

```
document.getElementById('submit-button').addEventListener('click', () => {
    // pick the value of the input
    const dateofBirth = document.getElementById('datepicker2').value;
    // same as yours
    if (dateofBirth != null && dateofBirth != '') {
        // Using the new modern fetch api to send the request
        fetch('insert.php', {
            headers: {
                // This is what was missing from your call
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            },
            method: 'post',
            // Building the data to send, basically you need a key value pair, so i gave it a 'data' key and value - the value of the input
            body: new URLSearchParams({
                'date': dateofBirth
            })
        })
        .then(response => response.text())
        .then(text => {
            // log the response in the console, for debug
            console.log(text);
        })
    }
});
```

Now, your insert.php file. You are wide open to SQL Injection attack with the current insert, so i have made some changes to include prepared statements.

```
<?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "testdb";
    
    // Create connection, no need to check if it succeeded, we will be extending the error reporting
    mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    
    
    $Date = isset($_POST['DateOfBirth']) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['DateOfBirth']) : null;

    if ($date !== null) {
        // build the sql query for prepared statement
        $sql = "INSERT INTO datepick (SinceDate) VALUES (?)";
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $Date);
        if ($stmt->execute()) {
            echo "New record created successfully";
        }
    }    
    $conn->close();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the attribute in the button tag, right now is submit, change it for button.

```
<button type="button" class="boxed-btn3" onclick="customFunction()">Next</button>
```